# Beginner: How to add permalink to WP_Query multiple custom post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm making a very simple page that displays multiple post types. How do I add permalinks to the values returned from `the_post_thumbnail` & `the_content`?

```
    <?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
    'post_type' => array('downloads', 'bjd', 'prints'),
    ) 
);
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();

    the_post_thumbnail('productgal-thumb');
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    the_content();

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Also, if I try to place these functions in simple `<div>` elements to format the style it breaks the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use it like this

```
<?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
    'post_type' => array('downloads', 'bjd', 'prints'),
    ) 
);
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('productgal-thumb'); ?> </a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?> </a>
<?php 
endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I did that and it breaks the code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $custom_query = new WP_Query( 
  array(
      'post_type' => array('downloads', 'bjd', 'prints'),
      ) 
  );
  if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();

    the_post_thumbnail('productgal-thumb');
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
    the_content();

    endwhile;
  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help you mate :)